# Mantle and Core Data : Only one Model

Tags: objective-c, core-data, model, nsmanagedobject

I'm starting to use Core Data with my Mantle Object (MTLModel) following this tutorial: http://chroman.me/core-data-and-mantle-one-to-many-relationship/

This article said :

> Since model classes inherit from NSManagedObject, which means that
>   they can’t inherit from MTLModel, we need to use  separated classes
>   for Mantle and Core Data

So, I have two class with the same properties:

- TrackMTL.m (MTLModel)
- Track.m (NSManagedObject)

**I'm looking for une solution without be forced to create two Model for the same Object and without use wrapper like [Overcoat](https://github.com/gonzalezreal/Overcoat).**

Comment: Then don't use Mantle.

Comment: And I use what? RestKit?

Comment: You don't have to use any third party systems at all.

Comment: I want save time, I receive my object from a Rest Api... It's the goal of mantle... actually you have any solution

Comment: @DamienRomito how did you solve your problem? can you share with your thoughts?

Comment: @TomHarrington, It'd be great if you gave any solution.

Comment: @ShamsiddinSaidov I already described what I think is best. Write your own code instead of trying to find someone else's and hoping that their idea of what's right matches your needs.

Comment: If it's really working as what we are looking for why to create new bicycle? And I didn't find any other most starred repo that solves my problem.

Comment: Last time I use https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync in swift. "Sync eases your everyday job of parsing a JSON response and getting it into Core Data."

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use 2 classes, just add this to your MTModel :

```
<MTLJSONSerializing, MTLManagedObjectSerializing>
```

and for the properties your have to implements this :

```
+ (NSDictionary *)managedObjectKeysByPropertyKey
```

Comment: Any chance you can provide an example of this? Cheers

Comment: @Ríomhaire here you are https://github.com/Mantle/MTLManagedObjectAdapter/tree/master/MTLManagedObjectAdapterTests