# How do you serialize API responses and persist objects without creating duplicate model classes for each entity in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch, core-data, realm

In an iOS app, I'd like to take parse the response from an API, serialize it, and then convert it into a form that can be persisted onto disk.

How do I do that without creating duplicate classes?

It looks like there's no direct way to [create Mantle objects and then save them into Realm](https://www.toptal.com/ios/simplifying-restful-api-use-and-data-persistence-on-ios-with-mantle-and-realm) without having two classes for each conceptual entity. You need a `MTLModel` subclass and a `RLMObject` subclass.

Ditto for [Mantle with Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720920/mantle-and-core-data-only-one-model).

Answer (score 0):

swift/objective-c support only single inheritance so a class cannot have more than 1 super class.

if you want to use Realm and Mantle you have to "duplicate" model for each framework

why do you want to use both? each seems to do the same thing just in a different way

Comment: I'd rather not have to deal with duplicates of every single entity class.